# JavaScript Promise wrong return

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm building a web shop with a NodeJS backend. 
I have promise that selecting user_id by token from database, and then I do another select to get cart data from specific user:

```
 function selectItemsFromCart(userToken){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    var queryString = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE token='"+userToken.token+"'";
    return dbconn.query(queryString, function(err, res){
      if(err){
        reject(err);
      }
      var userId = res[0].id;
       resolve(userId);
    });
  }).then(function(userId){
    var queryString = "SELECT * FROM cart LEFT JOIN users ON cart.user_id='"+userId+"'";
    return dbconn.query(queryString, function(err,res){
      if(err){
        return err;
      }
        return res;
    });
  });
}
```

When I trying to send it back to front like this:

```
app.use('/showCartItems', function(req, res){
  selectItemsFromCart(req.body).then(function(result){
    console.log(result);
    res.send(result);
  }).catch(function(err){
    res.status(500).end("Can't load cart");
  });
});
```

My console instead of showing me results of JOIN it shows this query log:

```
Query {
  domain: null,
  _events: 
   { error: [Function],
     packet: [Function],
     end: [Function],
     timeout: [Function],
     'start-tls': [Function] },
  _eventsCount: 5,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  _callback: [Function],
  _callSite: 
   Error
       at Protocol._enqueue (/var/www/html/Web Shop Yoon/src/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:141:48)
       at Connection.query (/var/www/html/Web Shop Yoon/src/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:214:25)
       at /var/www/html/Web Shop Yoon/src/script.js:155:19
       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7),
  _ended: false,
  _timeout: undefined,
  _idleNext: null,
  _idlePrev: null,
  _idleStart: null,
  _idleTimeout: -1,
  _repeat: null,
  sql: 'SELECT * FROM cart LEFT JOIN users ON cart.user_id=\'15\'',
  values: undefined,
  typeCast: true,
  nestTables: false,
  _resultSet: null,
  _results: [],
  _fields: [],
  _index: 0,
  _loadError: null,
  _connection: 
   Connection {
     domain: null,
     _events: {}....
```

How can I get the right return of my promise?

Comment: You're correctly using `reject`/`resolve` in your first `query` callback, but in your second `query` callback you're using `return` instead. Why? What do you expect those return values to be used for? `query` certainly doesn't (and can't) return them.

Comment: dbconn.query is asynchronous, and doesn't return a Promise, therefore you can't use it like that ... you seem to have done it right for the first dbconn.query, you just "forgot" to wrap the second one in a Promise as well - I would suggest creating a wrapper function for dbconn.query to Promisify it

Comment: Side note: The fact you're using Angular on the client is completely irrelevant to your question and potentially confusing to people reading it (see [this answer attempt](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40069350/157247), for instance, which mistakes the quoted code for client-side code). Since this is about as purely server-side as it gets, I would have suggested leaving the Angular thing off entirely (and have edited the question accordingly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just haven't fully promise-ified that code. Your first use of a promise with `query` is fine (other than a `return` that doesn't do anything), but then you haven't fully applied that to the second one.

In addition to that:

1. There is at least one seeming SQL injection risk, and quite probably two, in the code; while you may know from context that there is no risk, it's still usually worth using the features of the API that defend against it anyway.
2. When you get back an error in your first `query`, you're doing `reject(err);` (which is right) but then continuing on to code using `res[0].id`, which may well be throwing an exception if `res` is `undefined` or `null` (which it probably is). While that's *relatively* harmless (the exception will be converted into a rejection that will be ignored because a previous rejection is already in place), it's definitely not right. :-) You wanted an `else` in there.

See comments:

```
function selectItemsFromCart(userToken) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var queryString = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE token='" + userToken.token + "'";
        // WARNING!! SQL INJECTION RISK!! ------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        dbconn.query(queryString, function(err, res) { // Note: No return on this line, it's not used for anything
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {                  // Note else
                var userId = res[0].id;
                resolve(userId);
            }
        });
    }).then(function(userId) {
        // Note use of a new promise
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            var queryString = "SELECT * FROM cart LEFT JOIN users ON cart.user_id='" + userId + "'";
            // WARNING!! Potential SQL INJECTION RISK!! --------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            dbconn.query(queryString, function(err, res) {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(res);
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Alternately, there are libraries out there that take APIs using NodeJS-style callbacks with the `err, response` argument pair and convert them to promise-ified APIs instead, handling this plumbing for you.

---

Re the SQL Injection warnings, please see http://bobby-tables.com and this immortal comic:

[image]

Comment: Also i would change `if (err) { reject(err); }` too `if (err) return reject(err);`  calling reject doesn't exit a function.

Comment: @Keith: I just saw that and was flagging it up (although with a different solution). Good catch.